# Chrome Extension - Get entire text content of the current tab

Tags: html, text, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension where I need to get the entire text content on the current tab. Now I've a plugin which retrieves selected text from the current tab. So, in essence I'm looking for the ctrl-A version of it :). This is what I've done so far taking the hint from @Derek.

This is in my event handler(this is just one, there are other listeners too for `onUpdated` etc):

```
chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function(tabId,changeInfo,tab) {
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getSelection"}, function (response) {
      selectedtext = response.data;
    });
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getText"}, function (response) {
      alltext = response.data;
    });
  });
});
```

This is what I've written in the content script:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.method == "getSelection")
    sendResponse({data: window.getSelection().toString()});
  else if (request.method == "getText")
    sendResponse({data: document.body.innerText});
  else 
    sendResponse({});
});
```

However the `document.body.innerText` is returning undefined. I need the entire text of the current tab in `alltext`. Can someone help me out on this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use `document.body.innerText` or `document.all[0].innerText` to do it in the [***content script***](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html).
It will get all the ***text content*** in the page, without any HTML code.

Or you can use `document.all[0].outerHTML` to get the HTML of the whole page.

---

### Example

**In the Content Script**

```
function getText(){
    return document.body.innerText
}
function getHTML(){
    return document.body.outerHTML
}
console.log(getText());             //Gives you all the text on the page
console.log(getHTML());             //Gives you the whole HTML of the page
```

---

### Added

So you want the content script to return the ***text*** to the popup. You can use:

- `chrome.tabs.getSelected` to get the tab selected,
- `chrome.tabs.sendRequest` to send request to the content script,
- and `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener` to listen to requests.

**Popup page**

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getText"}, function(response) {
        if(response.method=="getText"){
            alltext = response.data;
        }
    });
});
```

**Content Script**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(request.method == "getText"){
            sendResponse({data: document.all[0].innerText, method: "getText"}); //same as innerText
        }
    }
);
```

This should work.

Comment: thanks @derek for the quick reply... but i'm not able to call this from inside popup.html where i need the text... sorry if this is something trivial that i'm messing up, i'm still kind of a novice...

Comment: i should also mention that i need it from the current tab that has been selected/opened...

Comment: For anyone reading this, Request is now deprecated in favor of Message: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709409/is-chrome-extension-onrequest-deprecated

Answer (score 3):

Use [`executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript): (requires permission `activeTab`)

```js
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    code: `document.all[0].innerText`,
    allFrames: false, // this is the default
    runAt: 'document_start', // default is document_idle. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/42509273 for more details.
}, function(results) {
    // results.length must be 1
    var result = results[0];
    process_result(result);
});
```

In case the `code` is complex, it's possible to define a function in the content script and call that function in the `code` (or use `file`).