# The code of chrome. tabs. executeScript to get the value of the JSON object is undefined. Why?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to get some values of the JSON object in the code of chrome. tabs. executeScript and send them out, but the value of JSON in the code is always undefined. Why?

Here's my bacground. JS code：

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(({ tabId, args }) => {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
    code: `
        var value = ${JSON.stringify(args)};

        var obj = value.trans_result;
        console.log(obj);

        var sendData = JSON.stringify(obj);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8088/info?str="+sendData, true);
        xhr.send();
        }
    `,});
});
```

Here's my manifest.json.JS code：

```
{
  "name": "chrome-extension-example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "10.0",
  "description": "test",
  "devtools_page": "index.html",
  "icons":
    {
        "16": "img/icon.png",
        "48": "img/icon.png",
        "128": "img/icon.png"
    },
    "page_action":
    {
        "default_icon": "img/icon.png",
        "default_title": "hello...",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
  "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "declarativeContent",
        "https://fanyi.baidu.com/*",
    "http://localhost:8080/*"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

and my manifest.json.JS code：

```
const log = (...args) => chrome.extension.sendRequest({
  tabId: chrome.devtools.tabId,
  args,
});
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(async (...args) => {
  try {
    const [{

      request: { method, queryString, url },

      getContent,
    }] = args;

    //log(method, queryString, url);


    const content = await new Promise((res, rej) => getContent(res));
    log(content);
  } catch (err) {
    log(err.stack || err.toString());
  }
});
```

thank you very much！

Answer (score 0):

The code that is executed by `chrome.tabs.executeScript` takes what you wrote there and interprets it in that tab's space. So it's using the value of `args` that is present in that tab's space, which is undefined. Basically the `args` in `var value = ${JSON.stringify(args)};` is different from the `args` above.

You could try

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(({ tabId, args }) => {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
    code: `
        var value = ${JSON.stringify(` + args + `)};

        var obj = value.trans_result;
        console.log(obj);

        var sendData = JSON.stringify(obj);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8088/info?str="+sendData, true);
        xhr.send();
        }
    `,});
});
```

Also, for what it's worth, `chrome.extension.onRequest` is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752341/chrome-extension-communication-between-content-script-and-background-html/11756188#11756188). It's [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709409/is-chrome-extension-onrequest-deprecated) that you use `onMessage` and `sendMessage` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried it. After writing this, only the "+args+" string will be output in the console. Now I don't need to study this question anymore. I'm looking for another function to replace him.