# Couldn't able to get the data for the current tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to chrome extension development and I want to get the contents of the current tab.

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499376/chrome-extension-get-entire-text-content-of-the-current-tab) question. But I couldn't able to see its working.

This is my `background.js` has:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab){
    console.log("Tab is been created " );
    console.log(tab);
    console.log(document.body.innerText)
});


chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,changeInfo,tab){
    console.log(document.body.innerText)
});

chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function(tabId,changeInfo,tab){  
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab){
chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getText"}, function (response) {
  console.log("Sending request ")
  alltext = response.data;
});
});
});
```

My content scripts like this:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if (request.method == "getText")
{
  console.log("In the request method" +  document.all[0].innerText)
  sendResponse({data: document.all[0].innerText});
}
else 
{
  console.log("came here in the else blog")
  sendResponse({});
}
});

console.log("Loaded the content ")
```

The log statement `Loaded the content` (but I couldn't able to see the logs coming in the `sendRequest` function, Why? ) is getting printed on the console, which means that the content script is loading. And in the extension manifest file I have given all urls like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }
  ]
```

But still I couldn't able to get the data of the current tab. I have been getting the following exception:

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://gndneapginhhkepodhngcbcbknfjfobj/background.js:33:21
    at disconnectListener (extensions::messaging:338:9)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at Event.dispatchToListener (extensions::event_bindings:394:22)
    at Event.dispatch_ (extensions::event_bindings:378:27)
    at Event.dispatch (extensions::event_bindings:400:17)
    at dispatchOnDisconnect (extensions::messaging:293:27)
```

where I'm making mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that `Request` was deprecated in favor of '`Message`'. So instead of `onRequest` you should use `onMessage`, and `sendMessage` as a replacement for `sendRequest`. See

[Is chrome.extension.onRequest deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709409/is-chrome-extension-onrequest-deprecated)