# Code injection using executeScript never call callback in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, code-injection

I am trying to create Chrome extension I am creating (intended to automatic fill form on third-party site - I know what you thought, not for spam, no). So when I am trying to inject JS into this page using executeScript it never calls callback function. Here is the code:

```
function doStepPopup () {
console.log ("Step "+step+" begins");
debugger;
var tab = curTab;
chrome.tabs.executeScript (null, {
    file: "extfiller.js"
}, function () {
    debugger;
    console.log ("Script injected for step "+step);
.........
}
doStepPopup ();
```

Second `debugger` function and `console.log` and all subsequent code never executing. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance! And sorry for my English...

Comment: Where does this code live in your extension, and what calls `doStepPopup`?

Comment: Guess: the first `debugger` makes the debugger window active so executeScript with `null` tab id tries to inject the script into the debugger window which fails, of course.

Comment: @wOxxOm Even if it failed, it should report the error by either an exception or `chrome.runtime.lastError`.

Comment: Is the path for the js file correct?  It's relative to wherever the script you posted is contained.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for interest in my question. There is no errors in console. As for trying executing code in debugger - it is very good guess but alas, I've put debugger there after realized that code working not as expected (not calling callback). It isn't working neither with nor without debugger directives as a pity. This function is calling from Extension "page". Here is my popup.html minified:
`<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>BK Survey filler</title>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
`

`popup.js` - is the file with code in question.

Comment: @Archer , Yes, path is correct. Found interesting behaviour - it is working perfectly when calling through `setTimeout` like `setTimeout(doStepPopup, 1000)` but direct call to this function leads to failing executing callback.

Comment: IIRC I've seen someone resolving a similar case by adding `runAt: 'document_start'` in [executeScript parameters](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript).

Comment: @wOxxOm, thank you! Will try this solution.

Comment: @wOxxOm, perfect! It really works! Please write the same as an answer to let me be able to accept it as a correct one. Thank you very-very much! You are lifesaver! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome.tabs.executeScript` by default injects at [document_idle](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) so it might not run on some weird pages that for whatever reason remain in "busy" state.

Solution: force an immediate execution with `runAt: 'document_start'`:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript (null, {
    file: 'extfiller.js',
    runAt: 'document_start'
}, function(results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```